# How fill the array

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops

I want to write code for calculating some values and put these values in a 2-dimensional array. I have written very simple form of this problem.

This code gives me no output.

I want to have one for example `m` by `n` array or matrix with elements which are calculated by specific function.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "cmath"
using namespace std;

double x;
int i,j;   
double A[10][10];
double M;

double function (double A,double x)
{
     for (i = 0; i = 9; ++i)
         for (j = 0; j = 9; ++j)
             M = 10 + x + A;
     return  M;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double y;
    cin >> x;
    y = function(A[10][10], x);
    cout << y;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the compiler objected to your indentation? Or your wanton mis-use of global variables. That aside, what output were you expecting?

Comment: "i < 10" and not "i = 9"

Comment: OP wants to know how to initialize a matrix in a function...

Answer (score 2):

This code has no any sense

```
{ for (i=0;i=9;++i) for (j=0;j=9;++j) M=10+x+A; return  M; }
```

You are assigning 9 to i and j in the loops. As 9 is not equal to 0 then these conditions `i = 9` and `j = 9`will be always converted to true and the loops will be infinite. Also it is not clear what you are trying to calculate by using one more invalid expression `M=10+x+A`

Comment: I mean I and j=10 ,I want to calculate elements of matrix or array.each element of matrix (M[i][j]) can be calculated by specific function.

Comment: Name M is not defined  as an array by you. So I still do not understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You use assignment `=` instead of equality `==` in your loop condition. Since `9` happens to convert to `true` your loops are infinite loops (BTW, you probably want to use `i != 10` and likewise for `j` anyway).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you intended to do:

```
 for (i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
     for (j = 0; j <= 9; ++j)
```

You were missing the <.
i < 10 would be the more standard usage.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help you to understand how initialize array.

```
double createValueFromIndices(int x, int y)
{
    return 10. * x + y; // or any wanted value;
}

void initArray(double (&a)[10][10])
{
     for (int x = 0; x != 10; ++x) {
         for (int y = 0; y != 10; ++y) {
             a[x][y] = createValueFromIndices(x, y);
         }
     }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double a[10][10];

    initArray(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3120411: There is no output, but the array `a` will be initialized. So `a[x][y] == 10. * x + y`, for example `a[4][2] == 42.`